# How can i pass parameters from controller to router in laravel?

Tags: laravel, search, routes, profile

I'm using jquery-ui.

Here is my code. I'm looking for search.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
data =[
    'Attock',
    'Pindi',
    'Pesha',
    'lahore'

];
$('#search').autocomplete({
  //  source: data,
    source: "{{ URL::to('autocom-search') }}",
    minLength: 2,
    select:function (key,value) {

     //   console.log(value);
    }

})

</script>

    public  function  search(Request $request){
        $req= $request->q;
        return redirect()-> route('/profiles/'.$req);
}



function show(User $user) 
{
    $users=$user->profile;

     return view('profile.profile',[
         'ProfileUser'=>$user,
         'User'=>$users,

         'posts'=>$user->posts()->paginate(2)
     ]);
```

If I simply add profiles/myname then it gives exact result but in the search function route is not defined. An error shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Route should be like this

```
Route::get('/profiles/{req}','SearchController@search')->name('search');
```

So your `return redirect()-> route('/profiles/'.$req);` should be replaced to `return redirect()-> route('search',['id'=>$req]);` 
[Named route redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

alernative to this `return redirect('/profiles/'.$req);`